# GL_INVALID_VALUE at glTexImage2D

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm getting a GL_INVALID_VALUE error after calling glTexImage2D()

```
GLCheckForErrors();  // no error
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
GLCheckForErrors();  // error printed here
```

I've substituted the values of width and height to 512 and 512 respectively and it solves my issue. This leads me to believe It's a power-of-two issue. But what I don't understand is i thought there was NPOT textures available with the opengl version I'm using?

```
OpenGL Version - 4.1 INTEL-8.28.30
GLSL Version - 4.10
Renderer - Intel HD Graphics 5000 OpenGL Engine
```

This should support NPOT textures fine right?

Thanks

Comment: By specs your code should indeed work. What you can try is: 1) replace the first GL_RED with GL_R8, 2) use a multiple of 4 width (and maybe height too).

Comment: It was my width parameter which was over 24,000. I assume that is just too large (it's a row of characters for a font texture). So I just got rid of the un-necessary characters i was loading and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My width parameter was too large it seems (over 24,000).

I was loading a series of characters in one long texture so all I did was remove the unnecessary characters to bring the width down and I'm no longer getting that error.

Another solution would be to just have a fixed width and then build up (but this was not going to be that easy for me due to each character having a variable width).

The relevant error condition from the [glTexImage2D() man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) is:

> GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if width or height is less than 0 or greater than GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE.

The limit for the texture size can be queried with `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, ...)`.

Comment: You should be able to query texture size limits. 24kx24k is a 576MB texture, that's *pretty big*.

Comment: It was 24k by like 200 because it was long ways. So not so bad. Its much smaller now.

Comment: The relevant error condition is: "GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if width or height is less than 0 or greater than GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE." You can query the maximum with `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, ...)`.